# Autonumbering in new entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an custom entity which needs to have a case number for an XRM Application, can I generate a case number from the Service -> Case.

If this is not possible, how can I do this with a plugin, I've looked at the crmnumbering.codeplex.com but this doesn't support 2011, anybody outthere have a solution or should I rewrite it myself?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into this same type of issue (I need a custom # for an entity). Here's how you can do it:

1. Create an Entity called "Counter"
2. Add a field called "new_customnumber", make it a string or a number depending on what you want
3. Create a new record for that entity with whatever you want in the new_customnumber field (let's say "10000")
4. Create a plugin (EntityNumberGenerator) that goes out and grabs that record (you'll probably want to set the security on this record/entity really tight so no one can mess with the numbers)
5. On Create of the "custom entity" fire the plugin. Grab the value in new_customnumber save it to the "custom entity" (let's say in a "case" field) increment the new_customnumber and save it to the Counter entity.

Warning, I'm not sure how this is with concurrency. Meaning I'm not sure if 2 custom entities being created at the same time can grab the same number (I haven't ran into an issue yet). I haven't figured out a way to "lock" a field I've retrieved in a plugin (I'm not sure it's possible).

You will be **unable** to create a custom number for custom entities from the normal area you set a case number.

Look at the CRM2011sdk\sdk\samplecode\cs\plug-ins\accountnumberplugin.cs plugin. It's really similar to what you want.

Ry

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen one for 2011 yet.  Probably easiest to write it yourself.

I've always created a database with a table with a single column which is an IDENTITY column.  Write an SP to insert, save the IDENTITY value to a variable, and DELETE the row all within a transaction.  Return the variable.  Makes for a quick and easy plug-in and this takes care of any concurrency issues.

The performance is fast and the impact to your SQL server is minimal.

Comment: I want this solution to be compatible on CRM Online as well, so SProcs are no go, but good answer though, since I didn't outline the compatibility aspect :)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this that is worked for CRM Online?  My basic suggestion would be to look at using Azure with a service endpoint that your plug-ing could call to get the number.  The challenge you will have with any other solution is avoiding the potential for duplicate numbers when to entries are saved at the same time.